# How to mount volume type LVM2_member to EC2 instance

Tags: lvm, mount, amazon-ebs, aws-ec2

I'm trying to mount a volume taken from an old EC2 to a new EC2 instance, however, this volume has an **"unknown filesystem type of "LVM2_member"**. I tried all this with the original volume, then I made a volume from the snapshot, thinking it would not be an LVM2_member, but it was identical , but without the nested structure of the volume. I found some instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002809/how-to-mount-a-lvm-controlled-ext4-file-system-stored-on-a-aws-ebs-volume-built?newreg=b92c344afdbb47aa857db6a568e05c90), but apparently that doesn't quite apply to this as it is not being viewed as a group or my syntax is wrong, or something else entirely different. Everything I try from whatever page I find doesn't work for one reason or another.  One thing to note, the guy this volume belonged to said he thought this was originally a shared volume with another coworker.  That coworker has a similarly named volume that wasn't mounted on his EC2 and he was ignoring it.  I don't know how long ago this was supposed to have been the case.  This guy's volume that I am trying to mount was successfully mounted and he thinks he was using it.

I'll go through the steps I have tried.

**STEP 1:** attach volume

**STEP 2:** `lsblk`  # will show me the root volume and other volumes I have tried.  mine is

```
NAME       MAJ:MIN  RM   SIZE   RO   TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
nvme4n1    259:6    0    100G    0    disk
```

**STEP 3:** `blkid`   # Gets me the UUID of the volume and shows me the TYPE

`/dev/nvme4n1: UUID="n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12" TYPE="LVM2_member"`

**STEP 4:** If I try to mount it: `mount n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12 /data`

`mount: special device n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12 does not exist`

**STEP 5:** Looking up that message it indicates that I need to make sure it is in my /etc/fstab file.

`vim /etc/fstab`

Yes, it is in there, because I put it there, but the type 'LVM2_member' isn't green, as the type is green for the other volumes.  Thus unknown type error probably as the type isn't being recognized.

`UUID=n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12 /home/ec2-user/data LVM2_member defaults,nofail 0 2`

**STEP 6:** `pvs`  # shows me the physical volumes on my device

```
PV          VG          Fmt   Attr  PSize     PFree
/dev/dsa12  VolGroup00  lvm2  a--     99.53g   19.00g
/dev/sdi    VolGroup00  lvm2  a--   <100.0g   <27.00g
[unknown]   VolGroup00  lvm2  a-m     19.53g       0
```

I know the /dev/sdi is the volume I am trying to attach. So we see there is a duplicate Volume Group name, and I already know they have different UUIDs.

**STEP 7:** `lvs VolGroup00 --config 'devices { filter=["a|/dev/sdi|", "r|.*|"]}'`

```
Couldn't find device with uuid c61234-9Mab-P12a-kabc-nab1-Fabc1-t1abcd.

LV        VG          Attr        LSize      Pool  Origin  Data%  Meta%  Move  Log  Cpy%Sync  Convert
auditVol  VolGroup00  -wi-----p-   8.53g
dataVol   VolGroup00  -wi-a-----   5.00g
homeVol   VolGroup00  -wi-----p-  20.00g
logVol    VolGroup00  -wi-----p-   4.00g
rootVol   VolGroup00  -wi-----p-  40.00g
swapVol   VolGroup00  -wi-----p-   2.00g
tmpVol    VolGroup00  -wi-------   4.00g
varVol    VolGroup00  -wi-----p-   9.00g
```

The /dev/sda12 shows similar info but without the "couldn't find xxx".

**STEP 8:** `vgs -o +vg_uuid --config 'devices {filter = ["a|/dev/sdi|", "r|.*|" ]}'`   # to get the volume ID

```
VG          #PV  #LV  #SN  Attr      VSize      VFree    VG UUID
VolGroup00    2    8    0  wz-pn-  <119.53g  <27.00g     jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef.
```

**STEP 9:** `vgrename jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef volnew` # rename volume using uuid

```
Couldn't find device with uuid c61234-9Mab-P12a-kabc-nab1-Fabc1-t1abcd.
Cannot change VG VolGroup00 while PVs are missing.
Consider vgreduce --removemissing.
Cannot process volume group VolGroup00
```

**STEP  10:** `vgreduce --removemissing jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef`  # Remove missing PVs

```
Cannot process volume group jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef
```

**STEP 11:** `vgreduce jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef c61234-9Mab-P12a-kabc-nab1-Fabc1-t1abcd` # I even tried that command using the id of the missing PV.

```
Volume group "jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef" not found
Cannot process volume group jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef
```

**STEP 12:** I found this [link](https://www.learnitguide.net/2017/12/couldnt-find-device-uuid-recover-lvm.html) that talks about recovering LVM metadata Linux. `cat /etc/lvm/archive/* | grep -i “jmt123-iabc-babc-Uabc-rabc-habc-gabcdef”`   # it shows what looks like history of the volume group before  certain executions like `vgchange` and `vgimport` and reference to the volume id, n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12.

**STEP 13:** `pvcreate --uuid "n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12" --restorefile /etc/lvm/backup/VolGroup00 /dev/sdi`

```
Couldn't find device with uuid n91234-wabc-Ua12-kabc-cabc-Gabc-oabc12.
Can't find uuid in backup file /etc/lvm/backup/VolGroup00
```

There is nothing in that file, I think.  I can't actually cd to the backup folder, but if I `ls /etc/lvm/backup` it shows `VolGroup00`. So vim to the file name VolGroup00 shows it is empty.

And now I am out of ideas and can't find any other pages/threads to give me further ideas to progress with the mounting of this volume on his EC2 instance.

My ultimate goal is to create a tar file of the data and upload it to an S3 bucket and then terminate the volume.